# Cross-Domain Cookie Consent with Subdomains

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, cookieconsent, cookiebot

Im using following domain/subdomains:

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) ( Blog )

login.example.com ( Login Portal )

my.example.com ( Members area )

Also Im using Cookiebot for cookie consent management.

Each time a visitor visits one of above domains, Cookie banner comes up and user is asked for consent. I enabled cross-domain consent. But still this doesnt help, could be because most browsers dont allow third-party cookies by default.

I have 2 questions.

1. Is there are a workaround for this to get Consent only once and not bother visitor again?
2. When Cross-Domain Cookies are enabled, all domains' cookies are collected in one consent. I count the Necessary cookies one by one they are 24 (when I click show details) on all domain/subdomains. However on Cookiebot Consent popup example.com(26), login.example.com(25) and my.example.com(24) therefore sometimes event cross-domain doesnt work although I enable the third-party cookies in my browser. What could be the reason for this? Please see below picture, I took screenshots using google chrome in incognito.

[image]